# Cannot SOURCE file in Flink sql-client

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I've been trying to `SOURCE` a file with SQL statements in the Flink sql-client. From the docs:

> SOURCE  Reads a SQL SELECT query from a file and executes it on the Flink cluster.

This uses the [Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/flink/1.13.1-scala_2.11/images/sha256-d5bf7db1d6978627c5f34d255974e5ee32e69e69f6bf4db7d21c98a33929395b?context=explore) for Flink version 1.13.1, Scala 2.11. Everything else about this Flink distribution works fine, as far as I can tell.

Within the container:

```sh
/opt/flink# echo "select 'hello';" > test.sql
/opt/flink# sql-client.sh
```

Then within the sql-client:

```sql
Flink SQL> select 'hello';
-- works as intended
[INFO] Result retrieval cancelled.

Flink SQL> source test.sql;
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteException: Non-query expression encountered in illegal context
```

I'm sure it's a very obvious mistake. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOURCE command is not a public API in previous version and it has been removed in 1.13. As an alternative, we provided `sql-client.sh -f test.sql` to execute a SQL file which is a way widely used in other systems. See more: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/sqlclient/#execute-sql-files

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected, just couldn't find the release note that mentioned the deprecation of `SOURCE`. I'm using the initialization mode with `-i` now, which works great.

Comment: In this -f mode however, SET command does not seem to work : 
SET 'table.dml-sync' = 'true';
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason:
org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "\'table.dml-sync\'" at line 2, column 5.

Comment: Hi, is it possible using -f option to execute the statements contained in a file, and then continue the session in interactive mode? This may be very useful  during development in order to try some experiments starting from a consolidated set of statements contained into the file.
Maybe this was possible using the SOURCE.